# how to add a list of files into an input value?

Tags: jquery, html, file, input, upload

I'm just wondering if this is actually possible, if it is not, why?

- add files via input type file multiple true
- files get stored in array of "FilesList" inside javascript
- when user is done selecting images, click upload
- upload all images in that stored array in javascript

```js
var storedFiles = [];

$("#inputFileId").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this)[0].files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this)[0].files.length; i++) {
      storedFiles.push($(this)[0].files[i]);
    }
  }
});

$("#inputSubmitId").click(function() {
  // add this storedFiles to an input is possible?
  // like $("#input").val = storedFiles;
  console.log(storedFiles);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>select any amount of images, how many times you want to</p>
<input type="file" multiple="true" id="inputFileId" />
<input type="submit" id="inputSubmitId" />
```

Comment: Yes, that's all possible. Do you have a specific issue?

Comment: How it's possible? yeah, i have the following error trying to 
`$(this)[0].files = storedFiles`
`Failed to set the 'files' property on 'HTMLInputElement': The provided value is not of type 'FileList'.`
typeof storedFiles = object

Comment: That's because you're attempting to set the value of an `input type="file"` control - you cannot do that. You will need to upload your aggregated file array via AJAX for this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upload files via js..It is an client side language...You need to use php or any cliend side language for that....
Here it is a website which includes it all:[W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Use multiple tag to get multiple images at a time and then using php store this images....